# How to set a Textbox to allow multiple lines, and scrollability

Tags: powershell, textbox, output, multiline

I am returning multiple different sizes of strings into a box.
I have used a `System.Windows.Forms.Label` but unfortunately some of the strings are too large for it, and do not display.
I have tried replacing it with a `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` but it will not let me set the height of it past 1 line, even with multiline set to true, and scrollbars set:

```
$objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox1.Multiline = True;
$objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,10) 
$objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$objTextBox1.Scrollbars = Scrollbars.Vertical
$objForm1.Controls.Add($objTextBox1)
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: you can try RichTextBox

Answer (score 7):

```
$objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox1.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,10) 
$objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$objTextBox1.Scrollbars = "Vertical" 
$objForm1.Controls.Add($objTextBox1)
```

Options for Scrollbars can be "Vertical", "Horizontal", or "Both".

Answer (score 2):

```
$objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox1.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,10) 
$objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$objTextBox1.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$objForm1.Controls.Add($objTextBox1)
```

Comment: It would be good if you could put a little description as well to explain why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

$objTextBox1.Scrollbars = Scrollbars.Both

```
[System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars].GetMembers().Name
```

Will give you posible memberconversions AND declared members

```
[System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars].DeclaredMembers.Name
```

Will give you posible declared members

ScrollBars will be None, Vertical, Horizontal or Both.